# How do I create multiple versions of an installer?

Tags: windows-installer

I have an MSI installer project. I need to be able to compile two different **versions** of the MSI (Download and CD). Certain files will be included in the CD version, and excluded in the Download version of the MSI.

I have created two **configurations** of the project. I am hoping to use Conditions to control inclusion/exclusion of the required files.

My problem is that I do not see how I can test for which configuration is being built. When I click on Configuration Manager, I don't see any place I can specify something resembling a manifest constant (similar to "Preprocessor Definitions" in a C++ project), that would vary depending on the Configuration.

The Configuration Properties dialog for an MSI project is pretty sparse, doesn't have any place to enter anything that could be tested by a Condition. Here is a screen shot:

[image: MSI Configuration Dialog]

The Property Page (F4) also doesn't seem to have any place for setting a variable that can be tested by a condition.

I am using Visual Studio 2010, migrating from InstallShield.

How can I customize depending on the Configuration?

Comment: This is a pretty simple tool, nothing that fancy available.  A simple workaround is to just add another Setup project.  Beware that Setup projects were declared obsolete for VS2010 and removed from VS2012.  No future, back to IS :(

Comment: I did not know that **VDPROJ** were no longer supported. Thanks for the heads-up! I will be looking at WiX. I loathe InstallShield. It has been our #1 support headache, with all its obscure, inscrutable error messages and quirks.

Comment: You could also have a look at Advanced Installer (http://www.advancedinstaller.com), it has an VS extension for VS 2012 and 2010, and much more advanced editing support in its own GUI. For the above problem, you will need to create separate projects too with the free edition, with the Professional edition you could set your own conditions and use a single project file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Bogdan Mitrache. _Advanced Installer_ looks promising. I have converted to **WiX**, which seems to be running well. Having multiple projects would be a drawback, because it would cause duplication of effort in maintaining the projects (almost same component list). I could not have gotten WiX to work without the information on StackOverflow.